# bodyParser.json on specific middleware

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

Basicly I need to bodyParse the request to be able to use express-recaptcha and therefor need to bodyParse it in that middleware but only there & not for the entire request.

Here's my middleware that I want bodyParser on (recaptcha.verify expects it to be json parser):

```
const recaptchaMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
  return recaptcha.verify(req, function(error, data) {
    logger.log({
      level: 'debug',
      message: 'Verifying recaptcha token',
    })
    if (error) {
      logger.log({
        level: 'error',
        message: `Error verifying recaptcha token for request`,
        body: error,
      })
      return res.status(403).send()
    }
    next()
  })
}
```

Here's my route:

```
  .use(
    '/api/v1/mandrill',
    recaptchaMiddleware,
    function (req, res, next) {
      logger.log({
        level: 'debug',
        message: 'Debugme',
        body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
      })
      next()
    },
    createProxy(EMAIL_API, { onProxyRes: metricsMiddleware('emailservice', []) })
  )
```

I could do the following hover the service im proxying to don't like that....

```
    const jsonParser = bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' })

  .use(
    '/api/v1/mandrill',
    jsonParser,
    recaptchaMiddleware,
    function (req, res, next) {
      logger.log({
        level: 'debug',
        message: 'Debugme',
        body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
      })
      next()
    },
    createProxy(EMAIL_API, { onProxyRes: metricsMiddleware('emailservice', []) })
  )
```

Summary: 
I need to bodyParser.json() on recaptcha.verify(req, function(error, data) and not the entire route

Comment: Basically every request that is made to `/api/v1/mandrill` will go through the every middleware that you defined in this code, so even if you move the parsing code to `recaptchaMiddleware` method every request body is decoded. No difference please correct me if Im wrong. I can't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: The request body is a stream that can only be consumed once, which in your case is being done by `body-parser`. I think that in order to solve this, `createProxy` needs to be implemented differently.

Comment: Basicly what I want to do is to validate the recaptcha from req.body through the express-recaptcha library as a middleware, then based on that I want to continue with the createProxy if it validates.